# How can I stop a NSTimer from being called over and over again

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, subview

I have a generated Subview that can be moved around. Every time it moves I check if it's passed 300 on the X-axis. My problem is, that when it passes the point and you don't stop moving it, the NSTimer gets started so often, that the program crashes.

```
NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];

for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    if (subview.frame.origin.x > 300) {
        NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        [data addObject:subview];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.00 target:self selector:@selector(callFunction:) userInfo:data repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zero You don't need a reference to the timer because the timer passes itself as the argument to the callback method. Timers don't invalidate themselves -- you need to invalidate them when you no longer need them.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a reference to `NSTimer` instances and when you don't want it to be fired anymore you can call `-[NSTimer invalidate]`

**Update** besides, is it your intentions to schedule timers in a loop?

Comment: When should I invalidate it? I'd have to invalidate it at the end of the if, but then i would invalidate it before it has started the function

Comment: it would help if you an post a crash details; as for overall scheme, why are you sending a mutable array wrapping a single view? Isn't it easier to send just a view?

Comment: ok so the problem was that I wasn't clever enough to read the crash details first. There was an outofrange exception or something like that and I only had to modify my other functions. Should i now delete the question? i'm not sure if I should but there's no real answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property where you save a reference to the timer. So you can always check if NSTimer is already started and you stop it by

```
  [NSTimer invalidate];
```

you add a property `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer`and then you can check like:

```
if(!self.timer){
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.00 target:self selector:@selector(callFunction:) userInfo:data repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: Seems it still crashes. I checked if(!timer.isValid){} before starting the timer.

Comment: But if i stop it right away it won't get to start the function and nothing happens.

Comment: Well I'm really thankful for your help but the problem was an OutOfRange exception or something like that and I only had to edit an other function. I feel like i should delete this question now, what do you say?

Comment: ok, but still this doesn not solve your problem with the `NSTimer`. Even if it doesn't cause your app to crash, you should not allocate `NSTimer` over and over. And next time it might be helpful to copy the crash message ;)

Comment: I'll just upvote and forget about this!! It was so stupid of me to ignore the crash message, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
[NSTimer invalidate];
NSTimer = nil;
```